# Python, Django3 error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'patterns'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am very new in Python and Django. I have problem with request in my app.
I want to get the value for pattern in part model (reletionship M2M)

And i have django error:

> '**QuerySet' object has no attribute 'patterns'**

What is the error and how to fix it?

Thanks for help

Models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Pattern(models.Model):  
    patternName = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patternName


class Part(models.Model):
    unitsList = (  
        ('szt', "szt"),
        ('m', "m"),
        ('komp', "komp")
    )
    partName = models.CharField(unique=False, max_length=128)
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=15)
    units = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=unitsList, default='szt')
    description = models.TextField()
    pattern = models.ManyToManyField(Pattern, related_name='patterns')

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.partName
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,
from .models import Part, Pattern


def partList(request):
    allParts = Part.objects.all()
    allPatterns = allParts.patterns.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'partList.html', {'parts': allParts, 'patterns': allPatterns})
```

partList.html

```
 {% for part in parts %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{part.partName}}</td>
                <td>{{part.code}}</td>
                <td>{{part.units}}</td>
                <td>{{part.description}}</td>
                <td>{{part.producer}}</td>
                <td>{{part.pattern}}
             
                </td>
                <td>
                   <!-- <a  href="../editPart/{{part.id}}">EDYTUJ</a>
                    <a  href="../deletePart/{{part.id}}">USUN</a> -->
                    <a  href="{% url 'editPart' part.id %}">EDYTUJ</a>
                    <a  href="{% url 'deletePart' part.id %}">USUN</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your field name is `pattern` without an `s`: `pattern = models.ManyToManyField`, but the view does `allParts.patterns.objects.all()` with an `s`. Change one of them so that they match.

Comment: The related name takes you from a pattern to its parts. Therefore `related_name='parts'` would be better, then you would do `pattern.parts.all()` to get the related parts for a pattern.

Comment: you're missing a closing apostrophe at the end of `'patterns'` 
`pattern = models.ManyToManyField(Pattern, related_name='patterns)`

Comment: also you have named your related_name patterns which would probably be parts
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the m2m on a queryset. `allParts` is a queryset of all the parts while `.patterns` points to the m2m related objects for each instance, not a whole queryset.

In order to get all the m2m relations for a queryset, you should perform a query like this:

```
parts = Part.objects.all() # or filter
patterns = Pattern.objects.filter(patterns__in=parts)
```

You can optimize the code to hit your database less:

```
parts = Part.objects.all().prefetch_related("pattern")
```

This way, django will perform one more query to get all the related patterns and adds them to each part in python. then you simply use the result without making extra database queries:

```
for part in parts:
    patterns = part.patterns.all() # this won't hit the database for each part.
```

Also, you need to use a for loop in your template since `patterns` will point to a  list of patterns and not just an object:

```
{% for part in parts %}
        <tr>
            ...
            <td>
            {% for pattern in part.pattern.all %}
                <span>{{ pattern.patternName }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
            </td>
            ...
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Side notes:

- You should probably use `parts` instead of `part` for a `m2m` relation.
- `related_name` used for reverse lookups meaning that when you want to access parts from `Pattern` model.
- Changing `related_name` to `"parts"` makes more sense since it's used on reverse lookup for `Pattern` model.

Comment: But I noticed that when i have only allParts =Part.objects.all() in views.py and add second "for" in html file everything work. Why?

Comment: It will but it will hit the database with a new query for each part but using `prefetch_related` in the view, will get all the related patterns and attach them to each part so when you call for patterns (`part.pattern.all`) there won't be a new database query. other parts were to explain that you can't call m2m on a queryset.